# Journey Builder - use contact data from data extension as journey entry source in decision split

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions, contactbuilder

i have a DE that is a join result of two synchronized objects (campaign and campaignmembers ). it gets updated every 3 hours by a sql query that appends new records to target DE called master_DE.
SQL also checks a field called [renponded = false ) to populate master_DE.

there is a 2nd sql that runs daily and updates only one field called (responded) on existing master DE records (pulling from same campaignmember synced DE object )

I would like to, on various points throughout the journey, to use contact data since it provides latest data , in decision splits to see if responded =true/false

is it possible to use the same entry source DE as contact data and if so can someone please give me the steps to set up master_DE as contact data? and what to do to make sure the decision split checks the field for the specific contact going through the journey.

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

1. To configure the Master DE as Contact Data, you can create [Attribute Group](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_cab_create_attribute_group.htm&type=5). Link your subscriber key or unique key with contact key in the contact builder.
2. This will check the conditions (responded =true) for that specific records in the Master DE.
3. Then you can configure your sendable data extension as entry source in the journey.
4. When you configure the decision split, use the attribute group you created. It will appear in the 'Contact Data' dropdown. You can select it and add the required condition checks.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_connect_data_extensions_for_decision_split_use.htm&type=5

Refer to the above SF documents.

Hope this helps.